# Why is my SQL query so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql

I run the following query on a weekly basis, but it is getting to the point where it now takes 22 hours to run! The purpose of the report is to aggregate impression and conversion data at the ad placement and date, so the main table I am querying does not have a primary key as there can be multiple events with the same date/placement.

The main data set has about 400K records, so it shouldn't take more than a few minutes to run this report.

The table descriptions are:

### **tbl_ads**  (400,000 records)

```
day_est     DATE (index)
conv_day_est    DATE (index)
placement_id    INT (index)
adunit_id   INT (index)
cost_type   VARCHAR(20)
cost_value  DECIMAL(10,2)
adserving_cost  DECIMAL(10,2)
conversion1 INT
estimated_spend DECIMAL(10,2)
clicks      INT
impressions INT
publisher_clicks    INT
publisher_impressions   INT
publisher_spend DECIMAL (10,2)
source VARCHAR(30)
```

### **map_external_id** (75,000 records)

```
placement_id    INT
adunit_id   INT
external_id VARCHAR (50)
primary key(placement_id,adunit_id,external_id)
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT A.day_est,A.placement_id,A.placement_name,A.adunit_id,A.adunit_name,A.imp,A.clk, C.ads_cost, C.ads_spend, B.conversion1, B.conversion2,B.ID_Matched, C.pub_imps, C.pub_clicks, C.pub_spend, COALESCE(A.cost_type,B.cost_type) as cost_type, COALESCE(A.cost_value,B.cost_value) as cost_value, D.external_id
FROM (SELECT day_est, placement_id,adunit_id,placement_name,adunit_name,cost_type,cost_value,
    SUM(impressions) as imp, SUM(clicks) as clk
    FROM tbl_ads
    WHERE source='delivery'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3 ) as A LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT conv_day_est, placement_id,adunit_id, cost_type,cost_value, SUM(conversion1) as conversion1,
    SUM(conversion2) as conversion2,SUM(id_match) as ID_Matched
    FROM tbl_ads
    WHERE source='attribution'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
) as B on A.day_est=B.conv_day_est AND A.placement_id=B.placement_id AND A.adunit_id=B.adunit_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT day_est,placement_id,adunit_id,SUM(adserving_cost) as ads_cost, SUM(estimated_spend) as ads_spend,sum(publisher_clicks) as pub_clicks,sum(publisher_impressions) as pub_imps,sum(publisher_spend) as pub_spend
    FROM tbl_ads
    GROUP BY 1,2,3 ) as C on A.day_est=C.day_est AND A.placement_id=C.placement_id AND A.adunit_id=C.adunit_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT placement_id,adunit_id,external_id
    FROM map_external_id
) as D on A.placement_id=D.placement_id AND A.adunit_id=D.adunit_id
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/weekly_report.csv';
```

Results of EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra          |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>         | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 136518 |                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>         | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   5180 |                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived4>         | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 198190 |                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived5>         | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  23766 |                |
|  5 | DERIVED     | map_external_id    | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 55      | NULL |  20797 | Using index    |
|  4 | DERIVED     | tbl_ads            | index | NULL          | PIndex  | 13      | NULL | 318400 |                |
|  3 | DERIVED     | tbl_ads            | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 318400 | Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl_ads            | index | NULL          | PIndex  | 13      | NULL | 318400 | Using where    |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: `The main data set has about 400K records, so it shouldn't take more than a few minutes to run this report.` I think you mean milliseconds...

Comment: Don't expect 100% uptime, kid (even though you're probably older than me), especially if you've been doing something so excessive for so long.

Comment: 22 hours is unbelievable.  How long do the subqueries take to run?  Something is not right about the queries.  There is no column `source` in the ads table, so this query should not run.

Comment: Indexing 100 rows takes about 4 seconds.  Do the math (475,000/100*4=19,000) and it should only take about 5.28 hours.  Consider checking how much RAM is being used a time on your computer.  If you've been running this for a while, it makes sense for it to slow down if you're running it twice the same time.

Comment: currently using 500MB RAM, last week I ran the same query against 350K records and it took about 5 hours

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` and post the results

Comment: Why are you joining `map_external_id`?  You're not using any of its columns.  Is it there solely to filter records?

Comment: sorry the query must have gotten cut off during copy/paste... the query does include map_external_id

Comment: Have you set indexes on the columns used in the `WHERE` clause? [What does `EXPLAIN` tell you about your query?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) Is `/tmp/` probably mounted from a different machine and thus not the query is what lasts so long, but the writing process?

Comment: running EXPLAIN now will post when I have results. @Wobbuffet, that is a good point I did run this query several times yesterday out of frustration of waiting

Comment: @feeela, no index on WHERE clause columns, but would it make much difference?

Comment: running each of the subqueries individually takes seconds

Comment: @user2647092 No, it makes a HUGE difference. Please use `EXPLAIN` to see what happens (as suggested above).

Comment: Have you monitored your server.  Do you other services running on the same server.  Check memory consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a speculative answer, but  I don't think 22 hours is too unrealistic..

First things first... you don't need the last subquery, just state

```
LEFT JOIN map_external_id as D on A.placement_id=D.placement_id AND A.adunit_id=D.adunit_id
```

Second, in the first and second subqueries you have the field `source` in your WHERE statement and this field is not listed in your table scheme. Obviously it might be or enum or string type, does it have an index? I've had a table with 1'000'000 or so entries where a missing index caused a processing time of 30 seconds for a simple query (cant believe the guy who put the query in the login process).

Irrelevant question inbetween, what's the final result set size?

Thirdly, my assumption is that by running the aggregating subqueries mysql actually creates temporary tables that do not have any indices - which is bad.
Have you yet had a look on the result sets of the single subqueries? What is the typical set size? From your statements and my guesses about your typical data I would assume that the aggregation actually only marginally reduces the set size (apart from the WHERE statement). So let me guess in order of the subqueries: 200'000, 100'000, 200'000

Each of the subqueries then joins with the next on three assumably not indexed fields. So worst case for the first join: 200'000 * 100'000 = 20'000'000'000 comparisons. Going from my 30 sec for a query on 1'000'000 records experience that makes it 20'000 * 30 = 600'000 sec =+- 166 hours. obviously that's way too much, maybe there's a digit missing, maybe it was 20 sec not 30, the result sets might be different, worst case is not average case -  but you get the image.

My solution approach then would be to try to create additional tables which replace your aggregation subqueries. Judging from your queries you could update it daily, as I guess you just insert rows on impressions etc, so you can just add the aggregation data incrementally. Then you transform your mega-query into the two steps of

1. updating  your aggregation tables
2. doing the final dump.

The aggregation tables obviously should be indexed meaningfully. I think that should bring the final queries down to a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, much appreciated! 

    Obviously it might be or enum or string type, does it have an index?

-> Sorry I accidentally left it out in the original post, but the source field does not have an index. I will add an index to all where cols to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Irrelevant question inbetween, what's the final result set size?
-> ~138,000 records

Have you yet had a look on the result sets of the single subqueries? What is the typical set size? 
-> Yes, there are 4 temp the largest two being about 40MB in size, with the final .csv output being about 36MB

My solution approach then would be to try to create additional tables which replace your aggregation subqueries. 
-> Great suggestion, something I never thought of but will definately experiment with this option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your advice. I ended up splitting the sub queries and creating temporary tables (with PKs) for each, then joined the temp tables together at the end and it now takes about 10 mins to run.